# Is the GLM a good fit or should I use a non-parametric test?

Tags: glmm, glmmtmb

I have been having trouble interpreting my data of seedsets of flowers. I have gathered data from seven flowering species in four different elevations. Not all the species appear in every elevation and the elevations are not equally spaced from each other. I would like to see if there is a trend in seedsets based on elevation, with "species" as a random factor (the seven species were chosen randomly, the criteria was that they should grow in at least two of the elevations).

The seedsets contain a lot of zero's which are important and which I want to interpret. I have gotten as far as to fit a zero-inflated negative binomial model to my data, but I do not know if it is a good fit. I am adding first the original model and the results, which I have tried to fit with a basic glmer with family poisson, from which it is evident that the AIC and BIC are very high and the residuals are too big. [image].

It was clear that I need to fit a different model and after some tries I came to the best one so far, which was a zero inflated model with the negative binomial family.

My question is, is this a good fit for my data, or is there another way to try and fit my data into a mixed model? Should I use a non-parametric test for my data? I haven't been able to find how low the AIC/BIC should be to consider it a good model. [image] .

I have also tried using the package DHARMa to plot the residuals, which seem to deviate significantly, but I am not sure if this is a problem when using the negative binomial distribution.[image]

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

First, AIC and BIC are useful for comparing models, not in isolation. For any one model, there is no "good" or "bad" level for these statistics.

Second, negative binomial regression does not assume that the residuals are normally distributed.

Third, is this a good fit?  I don't know. The model makes sense for the situation you have described. You can evaluate fit in various ways. I like to make plots of predicted values vs. actual values, of the residuals themselves, and so on. You can also look at the mean absolute residual and the extremes of the residuals, and so on. Whether these are "good" is really dependent on the field. You'd have to interpret them based on your knowledge of botany.

Finally, if you decide that the fit isn't that good, it may not be your choice of model. Unfortunately, it might just be that your theory of the relationship isn't that good, or that you are omitting important variables, or that the variables are measured with a lot of error (although that seems less likely here) or any of the other things that can go wrong. Sometimes, the conclusion is "we thought XXX was happening but we were wrong. More research is needed."